# Edit user profile for logged in user(codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

Help guys, is there any solution how to edit profile for logged in user, my code makes a change to all row, not a spesific row. it doesn't change only logged in user but for all user(row). So any idea?

here is my controller:

```
 public function updateData(){
    $param['first_name'] = $this->input->post('first_name');
    $param['last_name'] = $this->input->post('last_name');
    $param['email'] = $this->input->post('email');

    $this->Model_members->updateData($param);

    $data['title'] = "Passion";
    $data['subtitle'] = "Synergize people";
    $data['description'] = "Synergize people";
    $data['view_isi2'] = "profile1";
    $this->load->view('layouts/templates',$data);

}}
```

and this is my model:

```
public function updateData($param){
        $field = array(
            'first_name' => $param['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $param['last_name'],
            'email' => $param['email']
            );

            $this->db->update('users',$field);
            $this->db->where('id',$this->session->userdata('$id'));


            return 1;
    }
```

very appreciate for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$this->db->where()` before `$this->db->update()`

why?:

because `$this->db->update()` runs the query, the next line is only a beginning trunck of sql query, which is not executed, therefor all rows are updated.